# what is the difference between peak and max memory used in java?

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

I am using a Java profiler and it is saying that peak memory used is slightly higher than max memory used. Shouldn't these 2 numbers be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess max is the total memory currently allocated to the heap, peak is the biggest size the heap has ever grown. Since the size of the heap can go down as well as up (if `-Xmx` > `-Xms`), this sounds logical to me. I could, however be completely wrong. :)